# Storing confidential data in Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm creating a web application using Azure AD as the identity provider. I would like to store confidential data for each user in Azure AD or Graph API. According to documentation Azure AD user schema extensions and Graph API open extensions are visible for each application in a given tenant, and granular permissions are missing to restrict access for only a specific user [extension] property. Is there an option to store confidential data in Azure AD / Graph API which is accessible only by the app which creates it or for which permissions exists to specifically restrict access without restricting access to commonly used resources (like users)? For example I would like my application to be able to read and write `/users/{Id|userPrincipalName}/extensions/myconfidentialextension` while other applications (even in the same tenant) are prohibited to, while still allowing other applications to access other parts of the `/users/{Id|userPrincipalName}` resource.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at using [Azure Key Vault](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/key-vault/), since this is the best solution for your requirement. Storing data in Active Directory makes that it's available (too) broadly.

**For [Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-custom-attr):**

> The custom attribute is now available in the list of User attributes and for use in your user flows.

**For [Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-feature-directory-extensions):**

> These attributes can be consumed through Azure AD Graph API directory extensions or Microsoft Graph. You can see the available attributes by using Azure AD Graph Explorer and Microsoft Graph Explorer, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD (Entra ID now?) has some pretty robust access controls, so you should be able to restrict permissions for this app. I'm struggling to understand exactly what you're trying to do, but [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/123975/how-to-allow-azure-ad-app-to-access-information-on) post may help put you on the right track. You may be able to accomplish what you need with some security groups and app access policies.